# Warning: The import of `Module` is redundant except perhaps to import instances from `Module`

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've recently started coding in Sublime Text. This has brought to my attention some warnings I didn't notice when I used Leksah. So I got this one:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S
```

Gives:

```
Warning:
  The qualified import of `Data.Set' is redundant
    except perhaps to import instances from `Data.Set'
  To import instances alone, use: import Data.Set()
```

On the other hand, either of these two imports from `Data.Foldable` don't give any warnings:

```
import Data.Foldable (foldrM, mapM_,foldr,foldl',concat)
-- or
import Data.Foldable
```

So I'm not really sure what the warning for Data.Set means. I would expect "redundant" means that it's not necessary. If I remove the import it doesn't compile because I'm using a lot of things for Data.Set.

Meanwhile sitting next to it is `import qualified Data.Map as M` which also gives no warnings.

So I'm completely confused about what that warning is saying.

Comment: Show us enough code that we can reproduce it for ourselves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It generally means either :

- you import a module but you don’t use it at all,
- you import a module that is already imported by another module you import.

It may be the effect of some refactoring where you don’t use the module anymore. Or maybe you’ve anticipated the future use of this module by importing it.

This message is generated when you compile your project using the `-Wall` option.

Try to delete the line which shows the error, it often works ;-)

Comment: You are correct and it turns out I just did something stupid. I split one module into 2 separate ones, where the import wasn't needed anymore. The warning was telling me that I wasn't even using Data.Set at all. Which I didn't notice until I removed it and it compiled fine. Thanks, that was a really silly thing to be stumped by.

Comment: Is there any way to know *which* other module exports the module?

Comment: @bergi I would say "try and see" or looking at libraries source code. I don’t know any compiler option that could help you (but I don’t know every compiler option ;-).